# Cant open visual studio sharepoint project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I had been setting up new sharepoint development environment with SP2013 standalone and Visual Studio 2012 on a VM. After installing Sharepoint 2013, I installed visual studio 2012. However when I open a sharepoint project I get an error (screen dump provided here http://ibin.co/1v7oDUiUcgln). What could be it? Should I re-install from scratch or is it a problem with SP2013 vs VS2012?

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the developer tools I managed to import sharepoint2013 templates. you can download the template here.

http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/10/offline-install-of-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012.html